# MS Access: How to add 15 days to date (data type) in Access Web App

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013, ms-access-web-app

My question is simple, How do I add 15 days to a "Field with Data type (Date/Time)" in Access **Web App**.

There is a Field called Revenue Plan which is a 'Date/Time' Data Type. 
and in Billing Due I selected data type 'Calculated' and typed formula mentioned below

Tried :

1. [RevenuePlan] + 15  //didn't Work//
2. DateAdd("d",15,[Revenue Plan])   //didn't work//

these both didn't work. Please help me out with this.

Note: Its for **Access Web App**

Thanks, 
Satish

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax is slightly different for an Access Web App for the DateAdd function.

The correct syntax should be

```
=DateAdd(Day,15,[Revenue Plan])
```

Here is the relevant MSDN link:

[MSDN Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj249452.aspx)

Comment: Thanks buddy for your reply :) I got the result.

Answer (score -1):

Hello I could find the answer, Its below.

> =DateAdd(Day,15,[Revenue Plan])